# Install HP printer on 10.6.4 without Apple Update

Tags: snow-leopard, printing

Can I install a HP Deskjet Printer on Snow Leopard (10.6.4) without access to 'Apple Update'?

Scenario: Have an outside worker using a Mac on our secured Samba environment. We are not adding the Mac to our network due to security concerns. The worker does not have internet access at home, yet requires a HP Deskjet ([6540](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?cc=uk&dlc=en&lc=en&product=357211&)) installing for use in the office.

The [HP website](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c01855252&cc=uk&dlc=en&lc=en&os=219&product=357211&sw_lang=) mentions:

> To install the printer driver available in Mac OS X 10.6, simply
>   connect the USB cable to the printer and to the computer. The print
>   queue will automatically be created.

The printer is detected and installed, yet when trying to Print the OS complains that it needs to run Apple Update (I'm assuming to download the required drivers).

I can see the [HP Printer Drivers package for download from Apple Support](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL907) (at 450mb it's too large for me to get easily).

Is there another way around this? (ie to only download and install the drivers required for the individual Deskjet, not hundreds of others.)

Comment: sounds like a pickle, can you maybe, attach the printer to your own computer? and perhaps from ther download the right drivers and transfer them over to the Samba comp?

Comment: I don't have another Mac to do this with, this is a secured Ubuntu/Samba environment with Windows client machines.

Comment: dammit, ok hold on imma try something! and by the way, do you need another mac to download the files?!?!

Comment: ive been searching for a while, and it seems that all you need to doo is connect the printer via usb!

Comment: Definately doesn't work - have downloaded the 450mb file so I'm going to attempt to install again on Thursday (when the worker is back in).

Comment: good luck buddy, i even tried too get the file and extract the specific driver for your printer, however that exceeds my abilities!sence it was an instalation file, and i coulnt find the file in there rather

Comment: Thanks for trying, I havn't had a chance to attempt installing it yet - but will report back when I have!